# Linux: How to setup dns server via dnsmasq and connect a second machine with it?

Tags: domain-name-system, linux-networking, virtual-machines, linux-kernel, dnsmasq

Setup:
I have two vms running: prime and second. 
On the prime dnsmasq is installed.

What I need to accomplish:

Setting a second(machine) so it connects and looks for domain names on the dns server.
(aka ping to custom domain from second to the prime (dns server))

I need to configure: 
/etc/hosts 
/etc/dnsmasq.conf
/etc/resolv.conf

If something isn`t clear, just let me know and ill update the post.

Thanks you in advance !

Comment: and what is the issue, you want to resolv?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to edit on the second machine is */etc/resolv.conf* which should contain:

```
nameserver x.x.x.x
```

Where x.x.x.x is the IP address of prime. No need to edit */etc/hosts* or install *dnsmasq* on the second machine.